# iframes and IE8 emulation

Tags: internet-explorer-8, svg, emulation

Alrighty,

Our application uses SVG for displaying graphics, which are displayed fine using the unsupported Adobe plugin, Firefox and Chrome. However, IE9 is pooched because it does not support SMIL animations.

So now (when using IE9) I am attempting to display the graphics by emulating IE8 via, to get our nice shiny animations back.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

When I load the page into it's own tab the correct plugin is used and my animations work! Yay! But... this page is required to be placed in its own iframe in our application. When placed into its own frame, the IE8 emulation appears to break down. Even though the user agent in the frame in the frame is coming back as

```
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)"
```

it does not appear to be honoured, as the native SVG is kicking in and my animations are busted.

So my question, has anyone dealt with this issue before (rendering specific frames using different emulations) - or am I up a river with no paddle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try if [FakeSMILe](http://leunen.me/fakesmile/) works in IE9+ and if it supports enough to make your content work ok. FakeSMILe implements a [subset of SMIL](http://leunen.me/fakesmile/status.html) in javascript. It's really [easy to use](http://leunen.me/fakesmile/faq.html#dev), and shouldn't interfere with native svg animation support.